# values inside input box become null when i add new input box with javascript

Tags: javascript

when i add new input box with javascript function, previous input boxes become empty. here is the code:

```
<div id="field">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div id="error"></div>
<button onclick="Add()">add</button>
<script>
    let i=0;
    const Add=()=>{
        i++
        if(i<5)
        document.getElementById('field').innerHTML+=`<input type="text" id="value${i}">`
        else 
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='Error: Field cant be more then 5'
    }
</script>
```

what can I do to NOT change input values of input box on adding new input box with above codes.

Comment: You are overwriting the entire HTML content of `#field`, re-creating the existing inputs.

Comment: you need add the value attribute like this: value=${i} to input element

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the entire HTML content of ID field,

```js
let i = 0;
const Add = () => {
  i++
  if (i < 5) {
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    document.getElementById('field').appendChild(input);
  } else
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Error: Field cant be more then 5'
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div id="error"></div>
<button onclick="Add()">add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`element.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) so that you do not alter the HTML of the `div#field` :

```html
<div id="field">
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div id="error"></div>
<button onclick="Add()">add</button>
<script>
    let i=0;
    const Add=()=>{
        i++
        if(i<5) {
          let input = document.createElement("input");
          input.type = "text";
          input.id = "value" + i;
          let button = document.createElement("button");
          button.innerText = "delete";
          button.onclick = function(){
            input.remove(); //remove text input
            this.remove(); //remove this delete button
            i--; //decrement i
          };
          document.getElementById('field').appendChild(input);
          document.getElementById('field').appendChild(button);
        } else {
          document.getElementById('error').innerHTML='Error: Field cant be more then 5';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank u so much . I can't upvote, I don't have 15 reputation points yet : (.

Comment: one more error: onClick.
I want to make onclick on the button sir. which I have created with JS with same method above.

let button=document.createElement("button")
            button.innerText = "delete";
            button.onClick=`del(${j})`

Comment: @aakashsinghrajput Welcome to Stackoverflow. I updated my answer but keep in mind that "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.". If you face a new problem, it's better to ask a new question. Also, you should avoid "thank you" comments, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it, keeping in mind separation of concerns and avoiding the creation of unnecessary global variables could be:

```css
#error {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div id="error"></div>

<button onclick="Add()">add</button>

<script>
  const Add = () => {
    const inputContainer = document.querySelector('#field'); // this variable is not strictly necessary but I think it makes the code more readable
    const inputNotification = document.querySelector('#error'); // this variable is not strictly necessary but I think it makes the code more readable

    const inputCount = inputContainer.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').length // count how many input elements of type text are already inside the `field` div

    if (inputCount < 5) {
      const txtInput = document.createElement('input');
      txtInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
      txtInput.setAttribute('id', `value${inputCount}`);
      inputContainer.append(txtInput);
    } else {
      inputNotification.innerText = 'Error: Field can\'t be more than 5';
      inputNotification.style.display = 'block'
      event.target.setAttribute('disabled', true); // optionally, you can disable the add button if you reached the maximum number of input fields
    }
  }
</script>
```